# Sync app data over cloud to website

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage

In my application I want to give the user the chance to store their data in the Google cloud. At the moment I store the data in a SQLite database on the smartphone. Now I want to create a website, where users can login with their Google account and have all their data from the application.

What do you think is the best way to store the data in the cloud? I do not want to pay for any storrage. Is it possible to upload the whole database to the Google Drive folder from the user and get the data on my own website? Or is there an easier way to upload and fetch the data from the smartphone over the cloud to my website? Has Google any APIs for that or which Google Service is the best for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely have several options with the Google cloud but some of them are paid options.

- You could host your application on Google App Engine. App Engine gives you generous free quota, including storage up to 1GB. You will have to use the Datastore API over here to write your persistence layer. Beyond 1GB, you will need to pay for storage.
- You could opt for Google Drive, in which case you can easily integrate with the Google Drive API for Android and store this data under the particular user's Drive account. This would then shift the responsibility of having enough storage onto the User and this would well for you.
- Google Cloud also provides Cloud SQL as a storage option and you could use your App Engine application to integrate with Cloud SQL if you like a relational approach to storing your information, but this is chargeable.

Comment: Okay thank you for that. Are the 1 GB from App engine for each user or do they habe to use 1 GB all together? And another problem I see is that if I upload only the database to Google drive how can I read it out in my website? The login works with Oauth. Can I get the database from Google drive over that and can I read it out with php?

Comment: 1 GB is for your total application and not for each user. The data in Google Drive belongs to the particular user, so it will need to go through Authorization, so that your application can read it. So, unles s they have authorized it, there is no way I believe, you can get to it directly.